How to switch var with/without “this->”?
If there is a way in PhpStorm 2024.1 selecting a var to switch its with/without “this->” :
$this->departmentsCount 

    => 
    
$departmentsCount

and vice-versa ?

There is none setting to do this. Only to select with $ or without

Pleae point this option

Check this SO post
